# Calls to API Always Return “Authentication Credentials Were Not Provided” when accessed from Apple Shortcuts, but not from Postman

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework, shortcut

I’ve recently been developing a Django Application to auto-generate some schedules for me in TaskPaper form. I’ve been using django-rest-framework to automate a lot of the details of this but now I’ve come up against a problem I can’t fathom with authentication. I’m using django-rest-framework-simplejwt and the application is deployed on Heroku.

When I test my app on my own machine I get the expected results, I can request the token and then using that I can request the data I want, all this is done using Postman. When I deploy the application to Heroku, and still use Postman again it all works as expected. However when I try and use Apple Shortcuts to request the data, getting the token is fine but when I try and GET the data using that token I get the error “Authentication Credentials Were Not Provided”.

I looked through all the accepted answers and tried all the solutions there to no avail, so any help would be greatly appreciated and I can post any code snippets that might be required.

settings.py

```py
"""
Django settings for jarvis project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

...

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'polymorphic',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'watch.apps.WatchConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'jarvis.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2'
        ,
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'jarvis.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

views.py

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_200_OK
from rest_framework.response import Response


from .taskpaper import Document, BooleanTag, StringTag, DateTag, Task, \
    TemplateEngine
from .elements import Chunk
from routines.config.routine_factory import RoutineFactory


# Create your views here.

@csrf_exempt
@api_view(["GET"])
def create_schedule_today(request):
....
```

Comment: Can you post your setting.py code?

Comment: @AseelAshraf added it now :)

Comment: what is the request format ? provide example request

Comment: The request from Shortcuts?

Answer (score 1):

first consider install CORS:

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

and then add it to your installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)
```

You will also need to add a middleware class to listen in on responses:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',  
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',  
    ...
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Also , make sure your request header has the following :

```
Authorization: token 182ajhsba18jakknbhwi
```

i hope this solve your problem :)

Comment: Added that in and still get the same response

Comment: @JonathanRainer umm ,, double check on your permission classes inside veiws.py
kindly post it here